# How do I connect to Interbase 6 on a remote location from .NET?

Tags: .net, database, database-connection, interbase

What drivers should I use? Are they free?

How should the connectionstring look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With regard to drivers, Interbase 6 is the same as Firebird 1.0. You can get ADO.net drivers here, and yes, they are free:

http://www.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/

Note, that Interbase 6 uses a network protocol that transmits many more bytes than necessary, and makes a huge number of network connections for even simple things. It is highly recommended to upgrade to a newer version, like Firebird 2.1, which is backwards compatible, but where the network protocol works much better, and faster.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better not use Interbase 6 which is very old.

You can use newest version of Interbase of the fork of Interbase open source named [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org)

Here you can can some connectionstring for [firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=netprovider&id=examples)